# Prevent duplicate entries with url inputs

Tags: php, url, duplicates

I have a form that inputs url

dynamically, the user may input

```
www.stack.com  or
www.stack.com/overflow  or
http://www.stack.com  or
http://www.stack.com/overflow
```

how can I prevent to insert the duplicate entry to my database?

I've tried these

```
$url = (input url)

$search = str_replace("http://www.", "", $url);
$search = str_replace("http://", "", $url);
$search = str_replace("www.", "", $url);
$search = str_replace("/", "", $url);
```

at the last $search, I wanted to remove all the following character after "/" including "/"
what does follow?

Comment: Are you trying to save the `hostname` only? If so, did you already have a look at [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some who will stuck with the same question and drop here, here's the complete code for this

```
if((strpos($url, 'http://')  !== false) || (strpos($url, 'https://')  !== false)) 
{   $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); 
    if (strpos($url, 'www.') !== false)
        $host = str_replace('www.', '', $host);
    if (strpos($host, '/') !== false)
    {   $str = explode("/", $host);
        $host = $str[0];
    }
}

else if (strpos($url, 'www.') !== false)
{   $host = str_replace('www.', '', $url);
    if (strpos($host, '/') !== false)
    {   $str = explode("/", $host);
        $host = $str[0];
    }

}
else if (strpos($url, '/') !== false)
    {   $str = explode("/", $url);
        $host = $str[0];
    }

else $host = $url;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) method to do all of the work for you:

```
$url = ((strpos($url, 'http://') !== 0) && (strpos($url, 'https://') !== 0)) ? 'http://'.$url : $url;
$parsed = parse_url($url);
$host = $parsed['host'];
```

The first line will verify if the scheme's of `http://` or `https://` exist in the given URL. If not, it will prepend a default of `http://`. Without the given scheme, `parse_url()` will put the entire URL in the `path` index. With it, it will properly parse the host.

Alternatively, since you specifically want just the domain name, you can add the `PHP_URL_HOST` flag to the method-call as:

```
$url = ((strpos($url, 'http://') !== 0) && (strpos($url, 'https://') !== 0)) ? 'http://'.$url : $url;
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // this will return just the host-portion.
```

Normally, you would want to keep the subdomain-names for a given URL because a subdomain can differ greatly (and even be an entirely different website). However, in the case of `www.`, this is generally not the case. Given one of the statements above on how to get the current domain, you can remove `www.` with:

```
$host = str_replace('www.', '', $host);
```

Comment: Hi, just finished testing this function. The parse_url() won't work as expected, look at this: `$url='www.stack.com/overflow'; var_export(parse_url($url));` this returns: `array ( 'path' => 'www.stack.com/overflow', )` I guess she should better to use [this regexp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#83875)?

Comment: @Stano It works still, however, the hostname will be in the `path` parameter instead of the `host` parameter; I'll update my answer to reflect.

Comment: thanks @newfurniturey , I used $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); 
 $host = str_replace('www.', '', $host);
one question, do all the hostname started only with "www" or is there anyting other than "www" ? Sorry I'm new to this thing.

Comment: @IvorySantos If the website has a subdomain, such as `mail.google.com`, it does not include the `www.`, instead it's `mail.`. Another example would be `security.stackexchange.com`; here, the subdomain is `security` and the canonical name `www` does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by newfurniturey seems to be very good solution. Before calling parse_url you can run one check if http:// is missing from the url, if so then you can prepend the string with http:// and parse_url should work as expected then